# How can Json.NET perform dependency injection during deserialization?

Tags: c#, json, dependency-injection, json.net, ninject

When I have a class with no default constructor, i.e. using dependency injection to pass its dependencies, can `Newtonsoft.Json` create such an object?

For example:

```cs
public class SomeFoo
{
    private readonly IFooDependency _dependency;

    public SomeFoo(IFooDependency dependency){
        if(dependency == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dependency");

        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public string Data { get; set; }
    public int MoreData { get; set; }

    public void DoFoo(){
        Data = _dependency.GetFooData();
        MoreData = _dependency.GetMoreFooDate();
    }
}
```

During serialization, I only care of storing Data and MoreData (and the type of the object, but let's don't complicate things for the moment). Now, to deserialize, can I call something like

```cs
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeFoo>(jsonText);
```

**How can I let JsonConvert know about my DI container?**

(Note: A work-around would be to always have default constructors in my classes, and call Service Locator in there to get any dependencies I need. I'm just looking for some more clean solution without poluting my classes with such constructors).

Comment: possible duplicate of [DI and JSON.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140978/di-and-json-net)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49366916/3744182) by [CodeFuller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5740031/codefuller) to [How can I use dependency injection with .NET Core 2 API options?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49362734/3744182) for an elegant solution using a custom contract resolver which replaces `JsonObjectContract.DefaultCreator()` with the injected creation method.  Unlike solutions that use `CustomCreationConverter<T>` this works correctly with `PreserveReferencesHandling` and `TypeNameHandling`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I agree with the separation of concerns posted by Steven, and the answer Mark Seemann has posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140978/di-and-json-net). **However, if you still want to go this way**, here is a solution that may help:

Inherit a `CustomCreationConverter<T>`:

```
internal class NinjectCustomConverter<T> : CustomCreationConverter<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IResolutionRoot _serviceLocator;

    public NinjectCustomConverter(IResolutionRoot serviceLocator)
    {
        _serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
    }

    public override T Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return _serviceLocator.Get(objectType) as T;
    }
}
```

Then make sure you retrieve this converter instance via your DI container as well. The code below will deserialize **and** perform DI on your object:

```
var ninjectConverter = kernel.Get<NinjectCustomConverter<SerializedObject>>();
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(ninjectConverter);

var instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SerializedObject>(json, settings);
```

[Here is a complete working example](https://gist.github.com/cvbarros/9076378).

Comment: My personal alternative is to create a single IContractResolver that either maintains its own mapping for dependancies or that uses the DI resolver directly. This way you can simply inject an IContractResolver into the types that perform deserialization and the IoC is still strictly maintained. It's a very similar approach, but removes the 'dependancy' on a specific converter.

Comment: This only makes sense if you have access to the `SerializedObject`

Comment: @AndrewHanlon - care to share your `IContractResolver` impleentation, it sounds like what I am looking for

Comment: @ElFik Sorry, I don't have a good example on hand. But in essence, I had overridden the Create Parameter/Property methods in the `DefaultContractResolver` to *inject* the dependencies.

Comment: No prob, we got there by overriding `CreateObjectContract` in our custom `DefaultContractResolver`, getting the `JsonObjectContract` from the base method, then overriding the `contract.DefaultCreator` with a func to call the constructor of the type with our injected values.

Answer (score 16):

You shouldn't let `JsonConvert` know anything about your DI container. The problems you're experiencing are caused by a flaw in the design of your application. The flaw here is that you **mix data and behavior**.

If you separate the data from the behavior your problem (and many other problems) will simply go away. You can do this by creating two classes: one for the data, and one for the behavior:

```
public class SomeFoo
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public int MoreData { get; set; }
}

public class SomeFooHandler
{
    private readonly IFooDependency _dependency;

    public SomeFooHandler(IFooDependency dependency) {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void Handle(SomeFoo foo) {
        foo.Data = _dependency.GetFooData();
        foo.MoreData = _dependency.GetMoreFooDate();
    }
}
```

Since now data and behavior are separated, `SomeFoo` can be serialized without any problem and `SomeFooHandler` can simply be injected. `SomeFoo` has becomes a [Parameter Object](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html).

Comment: Rings a bell for the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), which could be quite helpful for what I want to achieve, thanks!

Comment: Ugh! Duh, I can't believe I didn't realize this. I'm making a task execution runner and I had tasks take in their dependencies *along* with options. I'll separate them so this is much more clean. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Why would you **always** want to separate data and behaviour?

Comment: @MarkT: This argument is expessed more clearly [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Comment: This argument only holds true if the behavior does not need to be serialized. In the case where it does, this point becomes invalid.

Comment: When using the pattern, how would you then apply it best to a collection. If I have a List<SomeFoo>, how best to apply SomeFooHandler to all?

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to use the injected dependency to modify the data, then you can create a custom `Converter`.

With this, you should be able to inject your dependency. Similar to the code below:

```
 var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Converters = { new FooConverter<T>(injectedDependency) }
            };
 return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dto>(json, settings);
```

There're many samples of how to create a custom `Converters`, so you can refer to them.