# How can I use dependency injection with .NET Core 2 API options?

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, .net-core

I have the below code in my startup configure services:

```
 services.AddMvc(options => options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true)
            .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
            .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
            .AddJsonOptions(o =>
            {
                o.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
            });
```

And the following model:

```
public interface ITestInterface
{
    string Hello { get; set; }
}

public class TestInput
{
     public string IWork { get; set; }
     public ITestInterface IDontWork { get; set; }
}
```

So on my controller action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody]TestInput testInput)
{

}
```

if I send the following JSON:

```
{
    "IWork": "I do work",
    "IDontWork": { "Hello": "hi hi" }
}
```

I get IWork correctly populated, but IDontWork is not. However, my interface is registered as a transient service... do I need to set something else in the JSON options or use my own contract resolver?

Comment: It would be great if you could illustrate the problem with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, it is not clear what you are attempting to do here. Where are you sending the JSON? Where are the interfaces registered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, my interface is registered as a transient service...

Yes, but Json.NET is not integrated with ASP.NET Core dependency injection. So the deserializer just does not know how to create an instance of `ITestInterface`.

> do I need to set something else in the JSON options or use my own contract resolver.

Yes, you should put some efforts to cover such a scenario and a custom contract resolver seems the most proper way for this. The steps that you should take are the following:

1. Define a custom contract resolver.
   You could base it on `DefaultContractResolver` used by Json.NET. You should pass instance of `IServiceProvider` to this resolver which will be used for instantiation of registered types.
2. In `Startup.ConfigureServices()` register all types that could be used by contract resolver during Json.NET deserialization.
3. Create instance of custom contract resolver and set it to `SerializerSettings.ContractResolver`. In `Startup.ConfigureServices()` you don't yet have access to `IServiceProvider` because it's not yet created (since services are still registered). However, you could create it by yourself by calling `services.BuildServiceProvider()`. But make sure you have registered all required services before this call.

Here is a sample that performs all described steps:

**DependencyInjectionContractResolver class:**

```
public class DependencyInjectionContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
    private readonly List<Type> registeredTypes;

    public DependencyInjectionContractResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IEnumerable<Type> registeredTypes)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));
        this.registeredTypes = registeredTypes?.ToList() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(registeredTypes));
    }

    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        JsonContract contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);

        if (registeredTypes.Contains(objectType))
        {
            contract.DefaultCreator = () => serviceProvider.GetService(objectType);
        }

        return contract;
    }
}
```

**Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) method:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<ITestInterface, TestClass>();
    //    Register all other services here
    //    ...

    services.AddMvc(options => options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true)
        .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
        .AddJsonOptions(o =>
        {
            o.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DependencyInjectionContractResolver(services.BuildServiceProvider(),
                new[] { typeof(ITestInterface) } );

            o.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
        });
}
```

Comment: If you use `services.BuildServiceProvider()` are you not creating multiple copies of a singleton? - [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core - ASP0000](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ASP0000)