# How to inject dependency into a JsonConverter<>?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, startup, jsonserializer

I would like to use a `JsonConverter<>` which has dependency, and that dependency can not be a singleton, instead should be resolve as scoped...

I have to configure my `System.Text.JsonConverter` in `Startup`, so I must provide the `JsonSerializaionOptions` along with my `JsonConverter<>` instance in `Startup`. I can live together the `JsonConverter<>` as singleton, I instantiate myself, but how can I inject its scoped dependencies?

The only horrible thing comes in my mind to have a `IServiceProvider` property, and some other logic later (middleware?) checks if that property is initialized and initializes it. So in the actual `Read` and `Write` methods of the `JsonConverter<>` can access to the scoped dependency via the `IServiceProvider`.

This sounds sooo errorprone and smells, once because of timing (what is the actual conversion occurs before the property injection), but my main concern is the concurrency, having this `JsonConverter<>` a singleton by design, so the very same IServiceProvider instance in the injected property will be used concurrently by all the web app threads...

What am I missing here?

- Is having a scoped dependency for a `JsonConverter<>` smells?
- Is there a way to not instantiate the `JsonConverter<>` in `Startup`? (yes I know I could instantiate JsonSerializerOptions and do manually the serialization with `JsonConverter`), but this way I can not use many built in json support of ASP.NET Core

Comment: What kind of logic do you wish to inject into that JsonConverter?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21861473/264697)?

Comment: Many thanks reading my question. In general: it is a request specific thing. The concrete case is the depends on browser timezone, which I could detect from my cookie. Why I would do this? Long story but the full issue with the JsonSerializer is described here in detail, it is closed, obviously was too much, imho it is clear :-)  https://stackoverflow.com/q/61984200/1157814